# Порядок следования полей в составном индексе

Tags: mysql

Как определить, каким должен быть порядок следования полей в составном индексе? Например, если в таблице есть два поля:

```
`refund_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`status` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
```

при этом поле `status` - с низкой селективностью (может принимать только значения 0, 1 или 2), то какое из этих полей должно быть первым в индексе, а какое - вторым?

Answer (score 1):

Все равно. Если отбор идет по двум полям, то используется весь индекс как единая сущность.

А вот при отборе по части полей из индекса, индекс будет использоваться только если эти поля находятся вначале индекса

**Update**

Как заметил @Fat-Zer, индекс не будет использоваться в случае сортировки по полям индекса, в случае если поля для сортировки указаны в ином порядке, нежели в индексе

Comment: Вообще-то, как раз абсолютно не «всё равно»... это зависит от запросов и при неправильно выбранном порядке индекс просто не будет использоваться.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Приведете пример запроса, который использует **все** поля индекса, при этом сам индекс не используется?

Comment: элементарно, например любой запрос с `ORDER BY` в обратном порядке,  т. е. если есть `INDEX (refund_date, status)`, то `SELECT … ORDER BY status, refund_date` вызовет полную сортировку всех записей. Более жизненные варианты включают группировку по второму полю с фильтром по первому...

Comment: @Fat-Zer За сортировку спасибо, я доуточнил ответ. А за фильтрацию я же четко написал _Если **отбор** идет по **двум** полям_. Безусловно если фильтровать только по второму полю, то индекс идет лесом. Ну так и это написано в ответе

Comment: «всё равно» в каком порядке индекс только в самом примитивном случае, когда фраза `WHERE` содержит оба поля в независимом виде... и обратный `ORDER BY` — это только один контрпример, когда это будет нарушаться...  создание корректных индексов и оптимизация запросов это достаточно обширная тема, а правильный ответ на вопрос будет не «всё равно», а «всё зависит от запросов, которые будут использовать этот индекс».